# How can I know if a trigram index is being actually used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

This question is a follow up for this thread:

[question about performance of ILIKE search with 2 wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629107/rails-improve-performance-of-simple-searching-method)

I asked help to improve the performance of a search method that consisted in ILIKE statements on several fields. I was proposed two solutons that I have implemented, first to concatenate the info from the relevant fields to search in order to avoid having 5 ILIKE statements, and the other one was to avoid regular b-tree indexes since they are not useful when looking for words using 2 wildcards. I decided to go with trigram indexes since I read about how they are useful in these situations.

The thing is, I haven't got any relevant improvement in performance, so I wonder if the indexes are being ued. The question is how can I know if these new trigram indexes are working?

I have tried explain analyze on my query but there is nothing said about the index:

```
Hash Join  (cost=971.56..2042.73 rows=3137 width=197) (actual         time=22.189..151.067 rows=2781 loops=1)
Hash Cond: ((part_variants.sap_cod)::text = (part_masters.sap_cod)::text)
Join Filter: ((part_masters.combinada_maestro ~~* '%rodamiento%'::text)    OR (part_variants.combinada_info ~~* '%rodamiento%'::text))
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 48682
->  Seq Scan on part_variants  (cost=0.00..826.52 rows=51506 width=64)   (actual time=0.005..7.943 rows=51463 loops=1)
->  Hash  (cost=853.88..853.88 rows=33625 width=133) (actual  time=21.496..21.496 rows=33653 loops=1)
      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 6310kB
     ->  Seq Scan on part_masters  (cost=0.00..853.88 rows=33625  width=133) (actual time=0.004..9.115 rows=33653 loops=1)
Planning time: 2.361 ms
Execution time: 151.276 ms
(10 rows)
```

The query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM part_masters INNER JOIN part_variants ON 
part_variants.sap_cod = part_masters.sap_cod WHERE (combinada_maestro  
ILIKE  '%rodamiento%' OR combinada_info ILIKE '%rodamiento%');
```

By the way, the execution time shown by explain analyze tool is way slower than the actual ActiveRecord time (around a second)

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way to index this starting and ending with %, you best bet is FTS that postgresql support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html

> Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, these index types also support index
>   searches for LIKE and ILIKE

So you should see your newly created indexes in execution plan. While your plan shows you use NO INDICES (`Seq. Scan`).

What you can do:

1. `analyze part_masters` and `analyze part_variants` (especially in case you didn't do it)
2. `set enable_seqscan to off` and check the execution plan again (to make sure indexes you created speed up the query)
3. If indexes speed up the query, but query planner do not use them despite the fresh statistics, check `effective_cache_size`, `enable_indexscan`, `random_page_cost` and so on to find why

Comment: Can you please indicate me which is the exact syntax for the point 1. From a `pgsql` session I try `analyze verbose part_masters` but i'm not getting any output

Comment: That was, thank you. `INFO:  analyzing "public.part_masters"
INFO:  "part_masters": scanned 800 of 800 pages, containing 34698 live rows and                   1018 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 34698 estimated total rows
ANALYZE
`

Comment: apparently analyzing the tables didn't make any difference for the planner. Setting seqscan to off then it uses the indexes but the execution time given by the planner is higher, 1262,716 ms. In production It still uses seq scan. Does set enable_seqscan = off only works for the current psql session or sets that parameter in a permanent basis?

Comment: `set` affects session, `alter database dbname enable_seqscan = off;` would affect db wide, but you should not use it this way. only to check if indexes are indeed benefitial or not. share your new execution plan on https://explain.depesz.com ?..

Comment: so it uses indexes, but you get slow on merge - I don't think you can fix it with index :) but anyway it answers that you index is indeed used, but it does not help - right?

Comment: Looking more carefully when setting sq to off it is actually using an index present on the field sap_cod which is not being queried...

Comment: Anyway, as you said, it looks like the index is being used or at least taken into account by the planner, but it doesn't help, which was the scope of the question. Thank you for your help, I learned a few tricks about pg this morning!